# Outlook addin: js code for 'task pane' called when 'action' is pressed

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook addin with 2 options: 1 buttons for an 'action' + 1 button for a 'task pane'.
I am testing my addin in an Office 365 Web.

In the **'task pane'** code (.js file associated to task pane), I have this code:

```
Office.onReady(info => {
    if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
        console.log("Hello from pane");
...
```

When I click the **'action'** in the addin, this code is also called ("Hello from pane" is printed)

Is it ok? If so, how can I know that the 'task pane' option is pressed, and NOT the 'action'?

The info in my XML manifest:

```
     <!-- New Appointment -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
        <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
          <Group id="Group">
            <Label resid="Group.Label" />
            <!-- Launch the add-in : action button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ButtonAction">
              <Label resid="Action.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="Action.Supertip.Title" />
                <Description resid="Action.Supertip.Desc" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>myAction</FunctionName>
              </Action>
            </Control>
             <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ButtonOpenPane">
              <Label resid="OpenPane.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="OpenPane.Supertip.Title" />
                <Description resid="OpenPane.Supertip.Desc" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="OpenPane.Action.location" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>
      
 ...
  
  <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="...FunctionFile.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="OpenPane.Action.location" DefaultValue="...taskpane.html"/>
  </bt:Urls>
```

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: That does not sound right. Is it possible that you reference this .js file from both task pane button HTML and action button HTML? Could you share you manifest? Also which outlook client you're trying this on and which version? Against what kind of account - Microsoft 365 or on-premises Exchange server?

Comment: Thanks, I added the info in the post

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance reference the .js file from both FunctionFile.html and taskpane.html? Does this issue reproduce on Windows or Mac Outlook too (if you have any of those clients) or only in Office 365 Web?

Comment: That was the problem, I had a reference to .js file from FunctionFile.html... I should have detected it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is not expected, unless you reference this .JS code from both function file HTML and task pane HTML.